# Better color coding for visual studio (2013)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, bluej, color-coding

I'm learning both Java and C# right now. I started with Java first, back in august. The class I'm using uses BlueJ as a compiler. BlueJ has this cool color coding, where it's not just key words or such, the background changes based on what exactly you're typing in.

(Because I'm terrible at explaining things, it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hJIT.jpg)
[image]

It's made it so easy on my eyes. Now that I've started coding in C#, my eyes can't seem to adjust back to not having the colors. I find myself getting lost in where an if statement begins and ends, and end up having to put ridiculous amounts of space and comments between code to help me follow it better. Does Visual studio have any options to do this, or do I just have to suck it up and learn to adjust?

Comment: is it express edition ?

Comment: http://studiostyl.es/

Answer (score 0):

The colour coding is in the *Fonts and Colors* options.  To get there select *Tools/Options*.  In the dialog, select *Environment/Fonts and Colors*.  For the code, you can set the options in the text editor but you can do it for all the other windows in visual studio too.

Comment: Cool, found that, but I don't really see a way to do it exactly the way I want it. I can definitely customize it now, but it doesn't look like I can specify if it's an if statement be this color, if it's a loop, be this color, or even differentiating between methods.

Answer (score 0):

### **Solution:**

You can download an extension. In Visual studio code, click on the [button that has four squares on the right hand side of the VS code's window.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrpUh.png) Then, in the search bar, search for "Bracket Pair Colorizer 2." This extension should aid your vision when looking at code. Here's an example
[picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Hsj.png) Also, this extension is customizable, letting you add any color you'd like to resemble different types of lines of code.

### Settings

To customize your extension, under the extension name you will find a settings dial, similar in shape to the windows settings logo. Click on that, and then click on "Extension settings". From there, you have access to many useful settings.

*If this solution has solved or helped you, please mark it as an answer and upvote it. Thanks!*

Comment: The OP was asking about `Visual Studio`, not `VS Code`